# Excel VBA - How To Insert Plain Value without Formula?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2003

I have skimmed many Excel VBA topics, however, I have not found any information about inserting plain values - the result of `SUM()` in this case - not formula. There is a method, `PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`, but it seems that it is not what I am looking for.

The following code example inserts the formula, not only the value:

```
Sub test()
    Range("A4").Value = "=SUM(A1:A3)"
End Sub
```

How do I insert plain values without the formula in Excel VBA?

Comment: Try please `Range("A1").Formula = "=SUM(A1:A3)"`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is what I think, you are looking for

```
range("a4").Value = Evaluate("SUM(A1:A3)")
```

Comment: I imagine the Value is not even needed all the work is being done by Evaluate? Also thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Are you wanting to the actual result of the `SUM`? I would try using `WorksheetFunction.Sum` eg

```
Dim MyRange as Range
With Worksheets("SheetName")
  Set MyRange = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(3, 1))
  .Cells(4,1) = WorksheetFunction.Sum(MyRange)
End With
```

Comment: Actually, parameters for Cell(,) are ROW and COLUM respectively. As a beginner this code is much more complicated to understand because of additional points before Range() and Cell(). Why WorkSheetFunkction? Is it good for better performance?

Comment: @reforrer Correct, parameters are row,column. I got it the wrong way round. I will edit. And yes I believe `WorksheetFunction.Sum` will be significantly faster than `Evaluate()` as `Evaluate()` will need to parse the string every time.

Comment: @reforrer The `.`s are used as shorthand (in this case) for `Worksheets("SheetName")` (this saves repeating it - see the [With statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx)). These extra qualifications are required in case you are wanting to refer to cells not on the ActiveSheet.